# Javafx Background Task

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

While working on a UI for another project, I discovered that I needed to run a background task to keep the UI responsive while updating elements of it in a loop.  Not knowing how to do this, I made a test project to play around with, and still not knowing how to do this, it failed, and I have no idea why.  I'd appreciate some help with understanding and solving the problem.

This test is supposed to make the two panes swap colors every half second, ten times.  What it is actually doing depends on the if statement and the sleep statements.

```
if(i%2 == 1)
```

Makes the console print

```
Pressed
0
1
```

Then a second or two later, the blue pane turns grey, and the whole thing stops.
When the statement is changed to

```
if(i%2 == 0)
```

The console prints the same thing, but this time the two panes swap colors successfully once, then both turn grey several seconds later.

When the sleep statements are commented out, everything runs as expected(the console prints out the expected thing at least), but it happens to quickly to observe, which is why the sleep statements were needed in the first place.

Here is the code:

```
public class Test extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    HBox root = new HBox();
    Pane a = new Pane();
    Pane b = new Pane();
    Button c = new Button("Swap");

    a.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    a.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");
    b.setPrefSize(100, 100);
    b.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");

    c.setOnAction(event -> {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
             @Override protected Void call() throws Exception {
                 for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    if(i%2 == 1){
                        b.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");
                        a.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else{
                        a.setStyle("-fx-background-color: grey;");
                        b.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                 System.out.println("Out of loop");
                return null;
             }
         };
         new Thread(task).start();
    });

    root.getChildren().addAll(a, b, c);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 100));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Comment: You can't change the UI from a background thread. Use `Platform.runLater()`, or (better for this case), use an `Animation`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out how to use Platform.runLater().  When I tried it, it made the entire UI freeze and become completely unresponsive, and even worse, the UI didn't update until after it finished running.

Comment: Do it the same way as in the sample code in the answer to the question I linked: i.e you wrap just the parts that change the UI in calls to `Platform.runLater(...)`. Obviously you should **not** wrap the `sleep(...)` in `Platform.runLater(...)`: you do not want the FX Application Thread to sleep.

Comment: Thanks, got it working.